# Is it possible to get Caller Id on iOS / iPhone without jailbreaking?

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm getting the impression that getting the caller id of an incoming call on iOS is not possible without jailbreaking.

Is that correct? Where can I find the official documentation that would tell me something like that?

Comment: if you making Ad hoc or In-house app there's some undocumented functions in CoreTelephony framework for example __GetMobileUserID(). But if you developing an app for Appstore apple may ban you for using undocumented functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you are right, you cannot get that information from the iPhone without jailbreaking
And since that is not available you will not find any information or documentation that talks about it